# How to interleave stderr and stdin to a std::process::Command?

Tags: rust

Looking at [the API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html), it doesn't look like interleaving (redirecting stdout to stderr in real time, or the other way around) is supported. How would I do it if needed?

Comment: If you're on Unix,I think you can use `to_raw_fd()` to get the file descriptor you want, and `from_raw_fd()` to construct a `Stdio` to give to `Command`.

Comment: Looked at how that would work, and found meself in a maze

Comment: Looking more closely, I agree I don't think it's directly supported.  A brute-force way would be to use the shell (ie install of spawing `my_prog foo`, spawn `sh -c 'my_prog foo 2>&1'`, though with some care for required quoting.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41019780/merge-child-process-stdout-and-stderr

Answer (score 0):

What's the source of confusion? You can create a `Stdio` object with [`FromRawFd::from_raw_fd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/os/unix/io/trait.FromRawFd.html), giving it a file descriptor to use as [`Stdio`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Stdio.html) implements the trait.

Comment: This answer only works on UNIX-like systems and is not cross-platform. Note the **unix** in the type name: `std::os::unix::io::FromRawFd`.

Comment: It would also be good to show a **complete** example where stderr and stdout are interleaved.

Comment: I don't see anything aggressive about "what's the source of confusion". I was just honestly asking. And yes, this solution is unix only. Maybe one could write a crate that abstracts this away for other platforms.

Comment: I believe you that it wasn't intended as aggressive, but I wanted you to know that it could be construed as such. I'd encourage you to highlight that the answer is UNIX-only when you add the example of it working!